# Unable to deploy gistic 2.0 package

Tags: git, command-line, command

I am trying to use a bioinformatics program GISTIC 2.0: https://github.com/ShixiangWang/install_GISTIC

Following the command line prompts:

```
(base) abkhan@Abduls-MacBook-Pro GISTIC % git clone https://github.com/ShixiangWang/install_GISTIC

Cloning into 'install_GISTIC'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 119, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (119/119), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (94/94), done.
remote: Total 119 (delta 63), reused 56 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (119/119), 22.24 KiB | 5.56 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (63/63), done.
(base) abkhan@Abduls-MacBook-Pro GISTIC % cd install_GISTIC
(base) abkhan@Abduls-MacBook-Pro install_GISTIC % chmod u+x install_GISTIC2.sh
```

These work successfully. But the next steps do not.

```
(base) abkhan@Abduls-MacBook-Pro install_GISTIC % ./install_GISTIC2.sh /Applications/GISTIC/GISTIC_2_0_23.tar.gz /Users/abkhan/Desktop
MacOS is detected, the GISTIC2 is for Linux at default, just take a try...
=================
  Preparing...  
=================
The install directory exists, exiting...
```

I did download the the gistic file and it appears in the directory using ls command:

```
(base) abkhan@Abduls-MacBook-Pro GISTIC % ls
GISTIC_2_0_23.tar   install_GISTIC
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I was being dumb, the error was telling me that the directory already exists and that I have to set the directory as a new directory